# How to make cursor always stay on textarea even if user clicks anywhere else on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, electron

I'm developing a Chat application using Angular & Electron.

I want user's cursor always on textarea where user types the message.
When user clicks anywhere else in the page, the cursor should not go away from text area. This helps user to type anytime from anywhere, it will type in textarea only.

I tried the following:

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.messageTextAreaInput.nativeElement.focus();
    }, 20);
```

I'm calling it on the textarea blur event. But this solution does not let me copy text from other messages. When I select any text from message history, my selection is lost.

Any other way to achieve this?

My app for reference:
[image]

Comment: _the cursor should not go away from text area_ - please do not do this? A website should never have control over the position of a cursor.

Comment: I came to say pretty much the same ^ thing. Please don't mess around with users ability to navigate. That would be very bad practice. It's going to look like a fault more than anything else.

Comment: But why do you want to do this? How would a keyboard user ever interact with the website with this? This is _not_ accessible

Comment: This is the user's requirement. There is no other input on that page.
Also, my client is currently using Trillian and he says that it is needed.

Comment: What about links? Buttons?

Comment: I have links and button on top they should work as it is. Also, adding a screenshot of my app in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", () => {document.getElementById("textarea").focus()});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" ></textarea>
```

Comment: This worked although one thing I changed is instead of window, I used querySelector for particular div and had to add tabindex="0" for that particular div. Using this, I was able to type inside the div and I am able to type in textarea

Answer (score 2):

Try this way. You can change focus element to your own element which can be focusable.

```js
const focusOnTextInput = () => document.getElementById('input').focus();

document.addEventListener('click', focusOnTextInput);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', focusOnTextInput);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
```

Comment: How would a keyboard user ever interact with the website with this solution? This is _not_ accessible

Comment: @evolutionxbox He asked only to mouse click action. If he will need to more complex situation I will give another solution

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.messageTextAreaInputClassName')) {
        document.getElementById('messageTextAreaInput').focus();
    }
}
```

So that clicking anywhere other than the text area will call the text area to focus.

Comment: But why though? This is _not_ accessible

Comment: This solution does not let me copy text from other messages. When I select any text from message history, my selection is lost.

Comment: User should be able to type from anywhere if chat is open, rather than just focusing during click event

Comment: `if (!event.target.matches('.messageTextAreaInputClassName') && !event.target.matches('.oldMessageTextClassName'))` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could check what key is pressed and optionally append the keypress to the text area. However you would basically need to create a small typing app to get the expected behaviour. Here is a small example, I use this to make a semi-interactive terminal like text area. The text area is disabled by default and keypresses are appended as needed AND stored in a variable called `input` which you could say is the message being typed.

```
let altCtrl = false;
let input = '';
let txa = document.getElementById("textarea");
window.onkeyup = function(event){
    if(event.key == 'Alt' || event.key == 'Control'){
        altCtrl=false;
    }
    };
window.onkeydown = function(event){
    let keyPressed = event.key;
    const regex = /[^\p{L}]/;
    const allowed = /[0-9@#\s]/;
    const modifs = [/Shift/, /Alt/, /Backspace/, /Control/, /CapsLock/, /Tab/, /Escape/, /NumLock/, /Home/, /End/, /PageUp/, /PageDown/, /Enter/];
    const noPrintModifs = [/Alt/, /Control/];
    if(altCtrl == false){
        altCtrl = noPrintModifs.some(rx => rx.test(keyPressed));
    }
    let isMod = modifs.some(rx => rx.test(keyPressed));
    if((regex.test(keyPressed) || allowed.test(keyPressed)) && altCtrl == false && isMod == false){
        txa.append(keyPressed);
        input = input + keyPressed;
    }
    if(keyPressed == 'Backspace'){
        txa.readOnly=false;
        txa.innerHTML = txa.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
        input = input.slice(0, -1);
        txa.readOnly=true;
    }
    if(keyPressed == 'Enter' && altCtrl){
        txa.append('\n');
    }
    if(keyPressed == 'Enter'){
        //do something with input text
        input = '';
    }
};
```

HINT: You may want to add more symbols to the `allowed` regex.